# EWS Oauth login expires, have to login every time application starts

Tags: vb.net, oauth, token, exchangewebservices

I am having problem in VB.Net code that connects to Mailbox using EWS. A mail account required 2F auth, 2F auth works but the problem is - EWS Oauth login expires, have to login every time application starts.

```
Using AcquireTokenSilentAsync, it doesn’t work 
authenticationresult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(serverName, clientID).Result
```

```
AcquireTokenAsync to authenticate
authenticationresult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serverName, clientID, clientAppUri, oPlatformParameters).Result
```

A VB.Net example that solves this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the access token, why do you need to recreate it every time instead of reusing `authenticationresult.AccessToken`?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: Once I get the token should I store it somewhere so that I can use it when I close and open the exe again?  Will have to ask user to login again after token expires?

Comment: Yes, if you get an authentication error, you will need to log in again.